# Mongodb - Querying on multiple less than conditions, one of which looks at a nested list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Basically, exactly what the title says.  I'm working on a statement to remove documents from mongo that are:

1. older than a specified timestamp
2. have less than 10 items in a nested list
3. Nested list has a field event that equals 'sale'

So far, I'm just working on a find condition to return documents that fits these criteria.  This is what I have so far:

```
db.shopping_sales.find( { $and: [{"events.event":"sale"},{ $where: "this.events.length < 10" },{$lt:{"latest_event_time":1610651388}}]} );
```

However, this is returning an error, where it does not recognize $lt:

```
Error: error: {
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1610652614, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $lt",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1610652614, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

How should this query actually be set up?

The data has this basic structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f11e5ac5bd848f7e70d7ceb"), 
    "events" : 
        [ {{ "event" : "Sale", "store" : "Sam's Club", "timestamp" : 1595008428.2717052, "item" : "clothes", "policy" : null } ], 
    "latest_event_time" : 1595008428.2717052, 
    "location" : "New York"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$lt` incorrectly; put the field name first and the `$lt` and parameter in it's own object; e.g.

```
db.shopping_sales.find({'latest_event_time': {'$lt': 1610651388}})
```

Comment: The use of `$and` here is also unnecessary.